# How are Thread Local Storage offset resolved in Linux Kernel?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64, thread-local-storage

I am learning about Thread Local storage and their usage in Linux kernel. I understood that it allows to store per-thread data. This is for instance the case when accessing the `current` `task_struct`.

I see that in my `x86_64` architecture this is done by using the global segment (`%gs`). My question is: How does `GCC` resolve addresses for this global segment (i.e. how does it translates `mov rax,QWORD PTR gs:0` in the `.(k)o` to `mov rax,QWORD PTR gs:0x17d80` in the compiled object ?)

Comment: Windows uses gs for thread info.  Does Linux?  gcc does not do relocation.  That's done by linker.

Answer (score 4):

The `.ko` is the compiled object. The `gs` prefix is emitted explicitly, the rest is just normal symbol relocation. For example, excerpt from running `objdump -dr amdgpu.ko`:

```
12b51:       65 48 8b 14 25 00 00    mov    %gs:0x0,%rdx
12b58:       00 00 
                    12b56: R_X86_64_32S     current_task
```

The `R_X86_64_32S` is just a standard symbol relocation, it will be resolved by the kernel module loader. The `gs` prefix is already there in the code.